# Kafka Streams: RocksDBConfigSetter parameterization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

If we have a class implementing the RocksDBConfigSetter, how to pass the parameter values (for e.g. blockCache, blockSize, writeBufferSize, maxWriteBufer) to that class.

streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.ROCKSDB_CONFIG_SETTER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyRocksDBConfig.class);

Also, is there any difference between setting the withCachingDisabled() on the storeBuilder versus withCachingEnabled() but setting the CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RocksDBConfigSetter` is described in the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#rocksdb-config-setter

```
public static class CustomRocksDBConfig implements RocksDBConfigSetter {

   @Override
   public void setConfig(final String storeName, final Options options, final Map<String, Object> configs) {
     BlockBasedTableConfig tableConfig = new org.rocksdb.BlockBasedTableConfig();
     tableConfig.setBlockCacheSize(16 * 1024 * 1024L);
     tableConfig.setBlockSize(16 * 1024L);
     tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true);
     options.setTableFormatConfig(tableConfig);
     options.setMaxWriteBufferNumber(2);
   }
}
```

> Also, is there any difference between setting the withCachingDisabled() on the storeBuilder versus withCachingEnabled() but setting the CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG to 0?

As of Kafka version 2.0 (and older versions), yes. If caching is enabled, the caching layer code will be executed, while with caching disabled the caching layer code will be stripped out and thus not being executed. If you set the buffer size to zero with caching enabled, this only triggers an immediate eviction from the cache. Thus, from a practical point of view, there is no much difference though.

Note, that this will be fixed in next release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6998

Comment: Hi Matthias, thanks.  For the second question, I accept the above answer.  Regarding my first question, sorry if I wasn't clear, basically we do not want to hard code the values (like blockCache, blockSize, writeBufferSize, maxWriteBufer) directly within the class, instead we wanted to get them from the property files that we use for the stream application.  Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you could put the config from the properties into a static object and let the `CustomRocksDBConfig` access this static object to set the values?

Answer (score 0):

This is too late for the OP, but for those looking to configure RocksDB state store settings, the properties passed into KafkaStreams will get passed to RocksDBConfig.setConfig().